# Как написать такое регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Всем привет! Нужно написать регулярное выражение для поиска в строке идентификаторов языка си.
То есть, идентификаторы, это имена переменных, методов и т.д.. Имена могут начинаться с маленькой буквы, а дальше любые буквы и цифры, а так же нижние тире.

Я написал такое выражение `[a-z][0-9A-Za-z_]` , но он работает некорректно

К примеру имеем такую строку: `var1 tqw var2_12 _qwe Str`

В результате должны быть: `var1 tqw var2_12`

А мне показывает вот что:

```
var2_12  # true
tqw      # true
var1     # true
qwe      # false, регулярка просто убрала символ _
tr       # false, регулярка убрала символ S, хотя нужно полностью слово убрать
```

Как будет правильно?

Comment: Может, `\b[a-z][0-9A-Za-z_]+\b`? См. [пример](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5ba-z%5d%5b0-9A-Za-z_%5d%2b%5cb&i=var1+tqw+var2_12+_qwe+Str).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```cs
\b[a-z][0-9A-Za-z_]+\b
```

См. [пример работы выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%5Ba-z%5D%5B0-9A-Za-z_%5D%2B%5Cb&i=var1%20tqw%20var2_12%20_qwe%20Str).

**Подробности**

- `\b` - граница слова
- `[a-z]` - строчная буква
- `[0-9A-Za-z_]+` - одна и более букв/цифр/`_`
- `\b` - граница слова

Comment: Благодарю, понял свою ошибку